# HP Procurve to Cisco - QOS

Tags: cisco, voip, qos, hp-procurve

I have a HP Procurve with the following:

```
vlan 4 
  name "Phones" 
  untagged 20 
  ip address 10.50.60.1 255.255.252.0 
  qos dscp 101110 

qos device-priority 10.50.100.10 dscp 101110 
qos device-priority 10.50.20.38 dscp 100010 
qos type-of-service diff-services
```

What is the Cisco equivalent command to accomplish the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming port `GigabitEthernet1/20` in the Cisco switch...

You need to define the vlan interface on the Cisco...

```
interface Vlan4
 description Phones
 ip address 10.50.60.1 255.255.252.0
```

Then assign a switch port to the vlan...

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/20
 switchport access vlan 4
 switchport mode access
 auto qos voip trust 
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

As far as defining maps for your QoS policy, it may be dependent on the model of your Cisco switch. 
You'll want dscp mode 46 for IP 10.50.100.10 (ef) and dscp mode 34 for IP 10.50.20.38 (af41).

My setups look like:

```
policy-map AutoQos-VoIP-Output-Policy
 class AutoQos-VoIP-Bearer-QosGroup
   set dscp ef
   set cos 5
    priority
    police cir percent 33
```

and on the port level...

```
 service-policy input AutoQos-VoIP-Input-Cos-Policy
 service-policy output AutoQos-VoIP-Output-Policy
```

What type of switch are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Cisco 3560G-48TS

Comment: How do I add the dscp mode for the IP addresses?